# Best way to store multiple data types to one array / table in java

Tags: java

I've got a small project I'm working on in which I'm trying to be able to pull data from a massive .txt file. The files got about 100 rows of the following:

```
Employee ID -- Salary -- Currently Employed == Employee Name == Paycheck Amounts
1 100 true == Michael == 300 200 100 300
2 200 true == Stephanie == 4000 2300 1000
```

Essentially I need to be able to call Employee ID at a later date and it shows their salary, employment etc. The other issue is that the paychecks could be either 1 paycheck or 50

I'm curious what are your thoughts on how to store this data? I can split the lines and what not to actually get it but what's the best method of storing it all at once.

Ideally what I would like to do is be able to call ID 2 and see its Stephanie and her last 3 paychecks were 4000, 2300 and 1000.

This seems like a bit of a big task for my small Java skills. Any thoughts / assitance would be highly appreciated!!!

Comment: Create a plain old java object (a pojo), and populate your array (or an arraylist) with instances of that type.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty standard stuff:

```
class EmployeeRecord {
  final int employeeId;
  final int salary;
  final boolean isCurrentlyEmployed;
  final String employeeName;
  final List<Integer> paycheckAmounts = new ArrayList<>();

  EmployeeRecord(
      int employeeId,
      int salary,
      boolean isCurrentlyEmployed,
      String employeeName) {
    this.employeeId = employeeId;
    this.salary = salary;
    this.isCurrentlyEmployed = isCurrentlyEmployed;
    this.employeeName = employeeName;
  }
}
```

Put these in an array

```
List<EmployeeRecord> records = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use map to store the data.

```java
Map<String, YourEmployeeObject> records = new HashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Employee Class ..

```
class Employee{
final int employeeId;
final int salary;
final boolean isCurrentlyEmployed;
final String employeeName;
final List<Integer> paycheckAmounts = new ArrayList<>();

Employee(
  int employeeId,
  int salary,
  boolean isCurrentlyEmployed,
  String employeeName) {
this.employeeId = employeeId;
this.salary = salary;
this.isCurrentlyEmployed = isCurrentlyEmployed;
this.employeeName = employeeName;
  }
}
```

Then create employee object
And add all employees to the list of employees

```
List<Employee> employees= new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: This is a verbatim copy-paste of another [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55755905/2745495).